# Show data by session

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

***Hello friends. I ask you to read the question I will ask again and again. My English is not very good.***
I have files named index.php, step 1.php, step 2.php, and finish.php. There are 3 different data interventions. name, surname, and age! I record this data in the database. I want to show this entered data on the finish.php page.

**But I have a problem like this.**
I see different information when the page is reloaded.

```
<input name="tel" type="text" class="text" id="tel" value="" tabindex="1" autocomplete="off" maxlength="11" title="Tel No en az 10 rakamdan oluşmalıdır" aria-required="true" required/>
```

Here I want to see the information entered in the finish.php file, but by "session ID".

What I want is to show only the information entered by that user...
The user is not registering. There are only data entries in the index.php file.
can you please help me, can you tell me what to do step by step? I can't find a solution and I don't know how to call.

***Turkish Translate:***
Türkçe yazıyorum, ilgilenen biri olursa çok daha iyi olur.
index.php dosyasında 3 adet input girişim var, ad soyad ve yaş olarak. Bu veriler sql tarafına sorunsuz kayıt edilebiliyor fakat finish.php dosyasında bunları görüntüleyemiyorum. Görüntülemeyi bir şekilde yaptım ama sayfayı her yenilediğimde sql' tarafına yeni bir kullanıcı veri giriş yaptıysa onu gösteriyor. Çözemiyorum..

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: I want information that can help me solve this. Not a site!

Comment: for this you should provide a concrete question!

Comment: I don't know how you can tell.
I asked my question, I would be happy if someone who understands comes out.

Comment: StackOverflow is not designed to give programming lessons

Comment: I tried to ask again. Would you check.

Comment: You should post all of the codes related to the question, e.g. php contents of index.php, step 1.php, step 2.php and finish.php

Comment: Türk görmek çok güzel :  Murat Tutumlu
Kodları atamıyorum çünkü çok uzun. Nasıl yapacağım?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sessions or cookies.Then, you can pass your data the sessions as follows.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["name"] = $_POST["name"];
$_SESSION["surname"] = $_POST["surname"];
$_SESSION["age"] = $_POST["age"];
```

In the finish.php you can retrive those data.

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION["name"];
echo $_SESSION["surname"];
echo $_SESSION["age"];
```

Comment: It happened. do not show.
You understand the question I want to ask. I can't solve this

Comment: I'm waiting for your help.

Comment: All you need is sessions. So read about [sessions](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) .